# USB As Website Root Causing 403 Forbidden

Tags: wamp

I've created an Alias which points to a USB drive (Drive F). The Alias has been created OK, but when attempting to access the root using `http://localhost/ALIASNAME` I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Is there something I'm missing? Is it something to do with the fact that its a USB or using Windows 8.1?

Thanks

Comment: Show the config for that alias

Answer (score 0):

I actually decided to use xampp instead as you can run  mysql and apache straight from the USB drive. Solved my issue